# capturing error from another python script in python/ Flask app

Tags: python

I've a python/Flask application where in python1.py, I have a route which invokes a function `funcpython2()` in python2.py.

If `funcpython2()` fails how can I capture that in my program?

`funcpython2()` has DB interaction & I've done exception handling at all possible points. When I say fail, I basically mean any unforeseen failure/error which stops the script from running. If that happens how can I capture that under `process()`?

python1.py:

```
@app.route('/process', methods=['POST'])
def process():
    funcpython2()
```